# Software testing awards/certification/recognition at Team/Company Level

Tags: team, certification, testing-team

We are looking for certifications / awards / recognition that are awarded to the whole testing team or the company. I am **not** looking for individual certifications like ISTQB, etc.

The purpose of these certifications would be to show that the QA / QC team, in our company, is recognized by `xyz`.

I was looking at [softwaretestingawards.com](http://www.softwaretestingawards.com/) and it seemed to be something that we are looking for, but unfortunately it is only for companies doing business in Europe, while we are limited to UAE.

Any pointers would help.

Comment: Is this for business or internal use ?
I have never heard of a test team recognition beyond personal certifications, there are certifications for process, like ISO 9000X, but they are not limited to a test group

Answer (score 2):

Organisations & events You can earn it for your organization in different levels.

- Recognition you can get having the business partnership with testing
  tool companies.
- ISO 9001 good one.
- Affiliation with university.
- Affiliation with testing organisations & participate in events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do have ISO. Affiliation with testing organisations and university would be great. I will do some research into that. Would you have any links/resources for these?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are based out of, but you could look into the ISO90001 in Europe. It is a quality management certification that applies to companies:

http://www.iso9001.com/

Comment: oops, I just noticed you stated you are limited to UAE

Answer (score 1):

You could have a test maturity assessment been executed, like [TMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_Maturity_Model) or [TPI(r)](https://www.sogeti.com/solutions/testing/tpi/). That gives you information about the maturity of the test processes in an organisation, and provides targets on improving maturity.